# python str.format with utf-8 characters that take more than 1 position

Tags: python, string-formatting, cjk

I trying to print japanese characters in python, aligned in columns. It seems that japanese characters have a width equivalent to two spaces, so the alignment doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
def print_kanji(s, k):
    print('{:<20}{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}'
        .format(s, k['reading'][0], k['reading'][1], k['kanji']))

# Being 's' some input string and 'k' a map which contains readings in the 3 different japanese alphabets.
```

The output I obtain is the following:

```
decir               いう        イウ        言う        

pequeño             すくない      スクナイ      少ない       

niño                こども       コドモ       子供        

ya [ha hecho X]     もう        モウ
```

The column in the left is spanish but that's not important. The important thing is that the 3 columns on the right are not aligned. I have counted the number of positions and it is correct, that is, the first japanese column always is 10 'positions' long, **the problem is that japanese characters are 2 positions wide while blanks are 1 only.**

I have checked as well that a blank (using the japanese input) is two positions wide as well, therefore I should be able to fix the problem by replacing the 'latin' space (1 position width) by the japanese one.

How can I change the character that `format` will use to align strings?

### EDIT

I have found that `str.format` has a parameter which is `fill`. I have tried to replace this by the japanese blank (two positions wide) and the result is worse.

### EDIT 2

I have solved it by implementing this function

```
def get_formatted_kanji(h, k, kn):
    h2 = h + str(' ' * (10 - 2*len(h)))
    k2 = k + str(' ' * (10 - 2*len(h)))
    kn2 = kn + str(' ' * (10 - 2*len(h)))
    return h2 + k2 + kn2

# being h, k and kn the three 'japanese strings' to be formatted in columns
```

however, is there a better (built-in) way of achieving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a terminal, it’s common for certain characters to take up two columns and other characters to take up one column. You can find out which characters are which by using the `unicodedata` Python module, which has an `east_asian_width()`.

Here is an example of how you can use it to pad your text:

```py
import unicodedata
table = [
    ('decir', 'いう', 'イウ', '言う'), 
    ('pequeño', 'すくない', 'スクナイ', '少ない'), 
    ('niño', 'こども', 'コドモ', '子供'), 
    ('ya [ha hecho X]', 'もう', 'モウ', ''),
]

WIDTHS = {
    'F': 2,
    'H': 1,
    'W': 2,
    'N': 1,
    'A': 1, # Not really correct...
    'Na': 1,
}

def pad(text, width):
    text_width = 0
    for ch in text:
        width_class = unicodedata.east_asian_width(ch)
        text_width += WIDTHS[width_class]
    if width <= text_width:
        return text
    return text + ' ' * (width - text_width)

for s, reading1, reading2, kanji in table:
    print('{}{}{}{}'.format(
        pad(s, 20),
        pad(reading1, 10),
        pad(reading2, 10),
        pad(kanji, 10),
    ))
```

Here is a screenshot of how this looks on my system (macOS):

[image: The same table, with columns lined up visually.]

### Limitations

The above code does not handle Unicode combining characters. A more complete implementation would perform Unicode text segmentation, and then figure out the width of each grapheme cluster. There are libraries that do this for you, I’m sure.

### Language Note

As a note, I don’t think the words “少ない” and “pequeño” are likely equivalents. The Spanish word “pequeño” refers to the size of something, and “少ない” refers to the quantity.

I think it’s more likely that

- poco: 少ない
- pequeño: 小さい

Comment: Is it only east asian characters that are double width, or are there others as well?

Comment: @MarkRansom: The character 'Ａ' (which is U+FF21) is double width, and it’s a Latin character.

Comment: @MarkRansom I believe the others are just what’s in the “Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms” Unicode block. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block). (But somewhat confusingly, that block also includes a set of “normal” width characters too: the “half” width versions of Japanese katakana.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the language formatting with:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ja-JP') # or 'jpn'
```